# Cancel ValueEventListener()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

please help me friends, i want to use "`addListenerForSingleValueEvent`" to get the list of values, and before that i run progressDialog. So when i get the values i cancel the progressDialog. But sometime network connection gets too slow, to which the value didn't get retrieved and the progressDialog keeps on showing for 5 to 10 minutes. so what i want is after after 15 second if progressDialog still showing then cancel the progressDialog and also `ValueEventListener();
i could cancel progressDialog but cant remove`ValueEventListener();

I tried below code its stop the `progressDialog' but can't remove`ValueEventListener();

when button is pressed, invoke start_retrieve() methode:

```
public void start_retrieve(){

    Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(myPd_bar.isShowing()){
                    myPd_bar.dismiss();
                    myRef_final.removeEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                    Toast.makeText(List_papers.this,"Network Connection too Slow!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, 15000); //after 15 seconds


     myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("results");
     myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {         
          //here code to receive data
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {            
            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.cancel();        
        }
        });
}
```

You can ignore my program, i know its wrong but if u know logic how to cancel `ValueEventListener()` afer some 10 to 15 seconds please share.

To know how "addListenerForSingleValueEvent" works, i connected my phone to my wifi router. So what i did is..i disconnected my Lan, so my wifi router is working but there is no internet connection and phone is connected to wifi which don't have any internet connection.
Now i pressed the button..after 15 seconds the progressDialog get dismiss.
I connected my Lan to my wifi router after 10 minutes..and to my surprise after 10 minutes still i received the data..which means "addListenerForSingleValueEvent" works in background infinitely. Please tell me how to stop "addListenerForSingleValueEvent"

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your definition for `myRef`. Probably you define `myRef` as generic variable out of functions and initialize it after `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {..`. Variables must be `final` in `Runnable()`, but if you do `final` you can't change myRef's value or reference. This may be causing an exception. You can create  `ref` first, then do what you want in `Runnable`.

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("results");
         myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {         
              //here code to receive data
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {            
                if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.cancel();        
            }
            });

Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                myRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Network Connection too Slow!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}, 15000);
```

**Edit:** I notice it now. `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` returns `void`. What is `valueEventListener` in the `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {..` and where did you create it?

**Edit 2:**

in your

```
myRef_final.removeEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

You create an instance of `ValueEventListener` with `new ValueEventListener()` then delete it with `removeEventListener`. The listener you removed in `removeEventListener`, is not a listener that you have already created.

Comment: edited..plse check the code and also the stopy.. :p XDD

Comment: k,,,then how i am going to remove the listener i created??